# How to convert ArrayList to String[] in java, Arraylist contains VO objects

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, classcastexception

Please help me to convert ArrayList to String[]. The ArrayList contains values of type Object(VO).

For example,

The problem is that I need to convert a country List to String Array, sort it and then put it  in a list. However I am getting a ClassCastException.

Comment: need more description, can you please paste code here

Comment: Properly override the toString() method of your class. And then do as Pramod Kumar has answered. That way no class cast exception. But you should know this is a bad workaround. You should find where your List is getting elements of a type other than Country. This is exactly what Java Generics prevent. So you might want to start using it...

Comment: I guess other guys got misunderstood of the question. The actual task is under your quotes below? Could you please clarify this? Take a look at my answer plz http://stackoverflow.com/a/11464855/538514

Answer (score 27):

```
String [] countriesArray = countryList.toArray(new String[countryList.size()]);
```

I have assumed that your country List name is `countryList`.

So to convert ArrayList of any class into array use following code. Convert T into the class whose arrays you want to create.

```
List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();    
T [] countries = list.toArray(new T[list.size()]);
```

Comment: This also will throw a ArrayStoreException.

Comment: It means that your are storing the wrong type of object into an array. You should reveal your code

Comment: It depends on what type the input list is :) I believe it is rather of type Value Object than the String type. You can see this in the question topic.

Answer (score 10):

> Please help me to convert ArrayList to String[], ArrayList Contains
>   Values Object(VO) as Values.

As you mentioned that list contains Values Object i.e. your own class you need toString() overridden to make this work correctly.

This code works. Assuming `VO` is your Value Object class.

```
    List<VO> listOfValueObject = new ArrayList<VO>();
    listOfValueObject.add(new VO());
    String[] result = new String[listOfValueObject.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfValueObject.size(); i++) {
        result[i] = listOfValueObject.get(i).toString();
    }
    Arrays.sort(result);
    List<String> sortedList = Arrays.asList(result);
```

The snippet of

```
    List<VO> listOfValueObject = new ArrayList<VO>();
    listOfValueObject.add(new VO());
    String[] countriesArray = listOfValueObject.toArray(new String[listOfValueObject.size()]);
```

will give you `ArrayStoreException` due `VO` is not the `String` type as required by native method `arraycopy` subsequently called from `toArray` one.

Answer (score 7):

In case your `ArrayList` contains `String`s, you can simply use the `toArray` method:

```
String[] array = list.toArray( new String[list.size()] );
```

If that is not the case (as your question is not completely clear on this), you will have to manually loop over all elements

```
List<MyRandomObject> list;
String[] array = new String[list.size() ];
for( int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++ ){
  MyRandomObject listElement = list.get(i);
  array[i] = convertObjectToString( listElement );
}
```

Comment: toArray(new String[...]) will work only if list is of the same String type, won't it? Assuming the question the list is of type ValueObject.

Comment: Thank you very much, it helps me a lot to solve my problem, I got exact solution. the code is,                                       List<CountryVO> countryList=new  ArrayList<CountryVO>();
  CountryVO vo=new CountryVO();
  vo.setName("Malaisie");
  countryList.add(vo);
  CountryVO vo1=new CountryVO();
  vo1.setName("Allemagne");
  countryList.add(vo1);
  String[] array = new String[countryList.size() ];
  for( int i = 0; i < countryList.size(); i++ ){
   CountryVO listElement = countryList.get(i);
      array[i]=listElement.getName();
  }Arrays.sort(array); Thanks to All

Answer (score 4):

```
String[] array = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

What are we doing here:

- `String[]` array is the `String` array you need to convert your
  `ArrayList` to
- list is your `ArrayList` of VO objects that you have in hand
- `List#toArray(String[] object)` is the method to convert List objects
  to Array objects

Answer (score 2):

As correctly suggested by Viktor, I have edited my snippet.

The is a method in ArrayList(toArray) like:

```
List<VO> listOfValueObject // is your value object
String[] countries  = new String[listOfValueObject.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < listOfValueObject.size(); i++) {
    countries[i] = listOfValueObject.get(i).toString();
}
```

Then to sort you have::

```
Arrays.sort(countries);
```

Then re-converting to List like ::

```
List<String> countryList = Arrays.asList(countries);
```

Comment: And this will throw a ArrayStoreException too.

Comment: @ViktorStolbin: thanks of your suggestion, have edited my snippet, plz check

Answer (score 2):

Prior to Java 8 we have the option of iterating the list and populating the array, but with Java 8 we have the option of using stream as well. Check the following code:

```
   //Populate few country objects where Country class stores name of country in field name.
    List<Country> countries  = new ArrayList<>();
    countries.add(new Country("India"));
    countries.add(new Country("USA"));
    countries.add(new Country("Japan"));

    // Iterate over list
    String[] countryArray = new String[countries.size()];
    int index = 0;
    for (Country country : countries) {
        countryArray[index] = country.getName();
        index++;
    }

    // Java 8 has option of streams to get same size array
    String[] stringArrayUsingStream = countries.stream().map(c->c.getName()).toArray(String[]::new);
```