# Convert List of File[] into File[]

Tags: java, file

I have List of File[] like this.

```
 List<File[]> fileList = new ArrayList<File[]>();
```

I need to convert it into a `File[]` something like this `File[] finalFiles`.

Is there any way that we can convert Array of `Files[]` into a Single `File[]`

Comment: This question is already answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464706/how-to-convert-arraylist-to-string-in-java-arraylist-contains-vo-objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java 7 Solution:

```
        List<File[]> fileList = new ArrayList<File[]>();
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++){
            count += fileList.get(i).length;
        }

        File[] finalFiles = new File[count];
        int pointer = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++){
            System.arraycopy(fileList.get(i), 0, finalFiles, pointer, fileList.get(i).length);
            pointer += fileList.get(i).length;
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the Stream API, you could have:

```
File[] finalFiles = fileList.stream().flatMap(Arrays::stream).toArray(File[]::new);
```

This creates a stream where each element is an array of files (`Stream<File[]>`), flat maps each array of files (so we have a `Stream<File>`) and makes a new array of all the elements.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly:

```
File[] finalFiles = (File[]) fileList.toArray(new File[fileList.size()]);
```